# How to fix laravel driver issue?

Tags: laravel, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-code

I have a project on a hosted server linking to mysql database. I downloaded the whole Laravel folder and now want to link to an azure sql server database using visual studio code.  The site displays fine but for any pages using a database I get this error Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException 
could not find driver

I have changed the database details in the .env file and the config > database file.  I added the mssql extension and was able to connect to the azure database there so there's no connection problems. I have downloaded mysql and added it to the system environment path. I tried commenting out the reference to mysql pdo in the php.ini file but that didn't work.

I have downloaded the two window drivers from here https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases to the php/ext file and referenced them in the php.ini file and ran composer update

Anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this now.  I think I had the wrong drivers.I went to the database in the Azure portal and clicked the php tab.  Clicked the link to download the drivers and extracted them to a folder. I am using php 7.3 so I copied two drivers into the php/ext folder.  Then in the php.ini file added references to the two drivers

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll
```

Ran composer update and then php artisan serve.  Viewed localhost in the broswer and the database connection is fine and the page displays.